# How to connect with c# language server client to language server

Tags: c#

I would like to use a c# language server client to connect and communicate with a language server. The language server client I found is here (https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol). In the examples I found code to create a client.

```
    protected virtual ILanguageClient CreateClient(Action<LanguageClientOptions> clientOptionsAction = null)
    {
        _client = LanguageClient.Create(
            options => {
                var (reader, writer) = SetupServer();
                options
                   .WithInput(reader)
                   .WithOutput(writer)
                   .WithLoggerFactory(TestOptions.ClientLoggerFactory)
                   .WithAssemblies(TestOptions.Assemblies)
                   .WithAssemblies(typeof(LanguageProtocolTestBase).Assembly, GetType().Assembly)
                   .ConfigureLogging(x => x.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace))
                   .WithInputScheduler(options.InputScheduler)
                   .WithOutputScheduler(options.OutputScheduler)
                   .WithDefaultScheduler(options.DefaultScheduler)
                   .Services
                   .AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(SettlePipeline<,>))
                   .AddSingleton(Events as IRequestSettler);
                clientOptionsAction?.Invoke(options);
            }
        );

        Disposable.Add(_client);

        return _client;
    }
```

But it is not clear to me how I can establish a connection to a language server (that is, to a language-server.exe). I found this example here (https://gist.github.com/tintoy/a2ec9424d17fe9ef17db0621479a7b43) but I think it's never has been working or with a very old version of the omnisharp language server client. But in general this is what I want to do. May be someone can give me a working example that can do the same thing like the example just mentioned.

Best regards,
Basti

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. With this example you can request code completion.

```
        ILanguageClient _client;
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var programPath = @"path\to\language-server.exe";
        info.FileName = programPath;
        info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(programPath);
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = info
        };

        process.Start();

        _client = LanguageClient.Create(
            options =>
            {
                   .WithInput(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
                   .WithOutput(process.StandardInput.BaseStream)
                   .WithCapability(
                    new CompletionCapability
                    {
                        CompletionItem = new CompletionItemCapabilityOptions
                        {
                            DeprecatedSupport = true,
                            DocumentationFormat = new Container<MarkupKind>(MarkupKind.Markdown, MarkupKind.PlainText),
                            PreselectSupport = true,
                            SnippetSupport = true,
                            TagSupport = new CompletionItemTagSupportCapabilityOptions
                            {
                                ValueSet = new[] { CompletionItemTag.Deprecated }
                            },
                            CommitCharactersSupport = true
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await _client.Initialize(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        try
        {
            var actualCompletions = await _client.TextDocument.RequestCompletion(
                new CompletionParams
                {
                TextDocument = @"path\to\someScript.py",
                Position = (23, 11),
                }, cancellationTokenSource.Token
            );

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var items = actualCompletions.Items;

            Console.WriteLine("items.Count: {0}", items?.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("actualCompletions: {0}", string.Join(",", items?.Select(p => p.Label)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).